# Why it's written Test Ad and how much time does google admob takes to show up on the android applications?

Tags: android, admob

I've implemented google admob in my application and I'm also using ad untis that I've created, not the test unit that are provided. Ads are shown and they are working but its written "Test Ad" over them. Can anyone help me why this is show.

[image: You can see it here]

Comment: you are testing on emulator?

Comment: Check on another phone which doesn't have gmail id which you used for AdMob and check on real device.

Comment: @MuntasirAonik Yes, I'm testing it over an emulator.

Comment: That's why the test ad is written, check on a real device.

Comment: @MDDanishAnsari Do I've to generate a signed apk or I can use debug-apk for testing?

Comment: AFAIK you won't get real ads with manually installing APK on emulator or even a real device. You get real ads for apps installed via Play Store only. But there's no loss in trying. Try unsigned as well as signed APK.

Comment: @MuntasirAonik On real device no ads are showing.